# react-joyride not accepting custom tooltip

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use react-joyride for a small tour. Everything works fine up to now, but if implementing a custom tooltip as described in the documentation, it fails with
`TypeError: Invalid parameter: element must be an HTMLElement`

I tried it with the most basic approach, because many elements in the example are undefined classes. It was supposed to just show up something, so I can play with the style and the props. I also tried to use other node tags or try to use the complete codesample and define the used classes with dummies. I also looked up some other demos/samples in the net, but to no avail.

Anyone has an idea, what joyride requests or what I have to use?

The code I use is:

```
import Joyride from 'react-joyride'
import PageTourModal from './components/PageTourModal'
[...]

class pageTour [...]

render () {
[...]
    const mySseps = [
      {
        disableBeacon: true,
        target: '[tourtag="Overview"]',
        title: 'Get a quick overview',
        content:
          'Gives you a quick overview',
      },
      {
        disableBeacon: true,
        target: '[tourtag="information"]',
        title: 'Information',
        content: 'Quickly get all information about your account'
      },
      {
        disableBeacon: true,
        target: '[tourtag="troubleshoot"]',
        title: 'Troubleshoot section',
        content: 'Look here if you run into any problems'
      },
    ]

    return (<Joyride
      steps={mySseps}
      continuous
      disableOverlayClose
      hideBackButton
      tooltipComponent={PageTourModal}
    ></Joyride>)
```

```
class PageTourModal

interface iPageTourModal {
  continuous: boolean // If the tour is continuous or not
  index: number // The current step's index
  isLastStep: boolean // The name says it all
  size: number // The number of steps in the tour
  step: any // The current step data
  backProps: any // The back button's props
  closeProps: any // The close button's props
  primaryProps: any // The primary button's props (Close or Next if the tour is continuous)
  skipProps: any // The skip button's props
  tooltipProps: any // The root element props (including ref)
}

const PageTourModal = ({
  continuous,
  index,
  isLastStep,
  size,
  step,
  backProps,
  closeProps,
  primaryProps,
  skipProps,
  tooltipProps,
}: iPageTourModal) => {
  return (<div>HELLO WORLD</div>)
}

export default PageTourModal
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone to stumble upon this:
I found the solution after some hours of searching and trying.
The custom component is only recognized as HTMLElement if the `tooltipProps` are passed to the main node.
Guess I wanted to have the modal too simple

```
const PageTourModal = ({
  continuous,
  index,
  isLastStep,
  size,
  step,
  backProps,
  closeProps,
  primaryProps,
  skipProps,
  tooltipProps,
}: iPageTourModal) => {
  return (<div {...tooltipProps}>HELLO WORLD</div>)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I spend a day and a half on this unhelpful error message. Most of the issues on Github for this issue are closed by the maintainer because the reporter didn't include a "Codesandbox" demoing the error. The issue looks to be that the `tooltipProps` holds the `ref` which must be forwarded to the "main node". The docs could do more to explain this.